# Paypal Sandbox randomly goes to Paypal Express

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using paypal payments with an IPN listener that redirect to a success.php page after payment. Currently testing with sandbox. All works fine except when clicking the pay now button, mostly it goes to the old style payment page but randomly it goes to the newer Paypal express payment page. This wouldn't be an issue except when it goes through the Paypal express page (not the old standard payment page), after payment is processed it redirects to the paypal users account page instead of the success.php as defined in the settings.

Is this just another sandbox glitch or is there a way to control which payment page it goes to. Also, how do I fix the redirect issue with Express payments.

[image: Paypal Standard payment page]

[image: Paypal Express Payment page]

Comment: An IPN listener wouldn't be redirected anywhere.  Maybe you're thinking of PDT..??

Comment: I am using an IPN listener. But I don't think that really has anything to do with the problem, I was merely stating that for some context. The ipn.php file is performing it's function correctly. The main issue is that the customer is randomly taken to two different payment style pages on sandbox when they click 'pay now' and I cannot see any reason why?!

Comment: PayPal is split testing those different checkout pages, so you'll see different versions randomly.  I'm pretty sure the live side is pretty much always showing the new pages now.

Comment: Had had a feeling that was the case but thanks for confirming Andrew. It's a real pain because it makes it virtually impossible to debug each version without knowing which one it's going to choose!